# Auth::user()->image giving blank array while am storing image as string laravel 5.3 mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel

```
@if(Auth::check() && isset(Auth::user()->image))
<img src="{{asset('storage/app/profile/'.Auth::user()->image)}}" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">  
@endif
```

its generating storage/app/profile/[]

using laravel 5.3 with mongodb

user model>>>
am having this model where image is also used in api
        namespace App\Models;

```
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
use Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'coordinates', 'kids','partener_name','partner_age','age','about_us','dogs','intrests'
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];
protected $with=['image'];

public function image(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Api\UserImage')->orderBy('serial','ASC');
}
```

}

Comment: Put `dd(Auth::user()->image) }}` after `@if`. What does it show?

Comment: its giving Collection {#252 ▼
  #items: []
}

Comment: in mongodb database field has value >>>"image" : "1478703290.jpg",

Comment: Can you show your `User.php` class in your question?

Comment: Not your question, but you have a typo on the $fillable array, last item.
Also, I recommend adding a line break after each item on long, constant arrays, such as that one, in order to increase readability

Answer (score 2):

You said `Auth::user()->image` is a collection. This means user has multiple images, so you need to iterate over them. For example:

```
@if(Auth::check() && isset(Auth::user()->image))
    @foreach (Auth::user()->image as $image)
        <img src="{{asset('storage/app/profile/'.$image->url)}}" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">
    @endforeach
@endif
```

If that's not what you want and you just one to have one image per user, check your `User` model. It seems you have `image()` relation which should be removed or renamed.

Comment: thanks @Alexey I got your point ,you are right i also created a relation and default $with with each user